# Kafka streams fail on decoding timestamp metadata inside StreamTask

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We got strange errors on Kafka Streams during starting app

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 7b
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:743)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:535)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:558)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.decodeTimestamp(StreamTask.java:985)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeTaskTime(StreamTask.java:303)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeMetadata(StreamTask.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.initializeNewTasks(AssignedTasks.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.updateNewAndRestoringTasks(TaskManager.java:385)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:769)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:698)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:671)
```

and, as a result, error about failed stream: `ERROR KafkaStreams - stream-client [xxx] All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed.`

According to code inside `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask`, failure happened due to error in decoding timestamp metadata (`StreamTask.decodeTimestamp()`). It happened on prod, and can't reproduce on stage. 
What could be the root cause of such errors?

Extra info: our app uses Kafka-Streams and consumes messages from several kafka brokers using the same `application.id` and `state.dir` (actually we switch from one broker to another, but during some period we connected to both brokers, so we have two kafka streams, one per each broker). As I understand, consumer group lives on broker side (so shouldn't be a problem), but state dir is on client side. Maybe some race condition occurred due to using the same `state.dir` for two kafka streams? could it be the root cause?

We use `kafka-streams` v.`2.4.0`, `kafka-clients` v.`2.4.0`, Kafka Broker v.`1.1.1`, with the following configs:

```
default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
default.timestamp.extractor: org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.WallclockTimestampExtractor
default.deserialization.exception.handler: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler
commit.interval.ms: 5000
num.stream.threads: 1
auto.offset.reset: latest
```

Comment: Unclear how this could happen. Kafka Streams would encode a timestamp in the commit metadata and tries to decode this timestamp later on. Not sure if/how this metadata could get corrupted. Could it be that some other client did a manual commit including some commit metadata for the corresponding `application.id` (ie, `group.id`)?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I updated post with extra info regarding reusing the same `state.dir` value for two brokers. maybe it somehow corrupt commit metadata, or race condition occurred.  it's impossible scenario with manual commit, we connected only via Kafka Streams

Comment: The state directory seems irrelevant for this issue. Maybe it was a transient network issue that "flipped" a bit? -- If you really want to dig deep, you could inspect the `__committed_offsets` topic via `bin/kafka-dump-log.sh` to see if there is corrupted metadata or not -- but this really goes down the rabbit hole. -- Or there might be some bug, but it's unclear what it could be.

Comment: thank you, will try to play around with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, we figured out what is the root cause of corrupted metadata by some consumer groups.
It was one of our internal monitoring tool (written with `pykafka`) that corrupted metadata by temporarily inactive consumer groups.
Metadata were unencrupted and contained invalid data like the following: `{"consumer_id": "", "hostname": "monitoring-xxx"}`.
In order to understand what exactly we have in consumer metadata, we could use the following code:

```
Map<String, Object> config = Map.of( "group.id", "...", "bootstrap.servers", "...");
String topicName = "...";
Consumer<byte[], byte[]> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]>(config, new ByteArrayDeserializer(), new ByteArrayDeserializer());
Set<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = kafkaConsumer.partitionsFor(topicName).stream()
        .map(partitionInfo -> new TopicPartition(topicName, partitionInfo.partition()))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
kafkaConsumer.committed(topicPartitions).forEach((key, value) ->
    System.out.println("Partition: " + key + " metadata: " + (value != null ? value.metadata() : null)));
```

Several options to fix already corrupted metadata:

- change consumer group to a new one. caution that you might lose or duplicate messages depending on the `latest` or `earliest` offset reset policy. so for some cases, this option might be not acceptable
- overwrite metadata manually (timestamp is encoded according to logic inside `StreamTask.decodeTimestamp()`):

  `Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> updatedTopicPartitionToOffsetMetadataMap = kafkaConsumer.committed(topicPartitions).entrySet().stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, (entry) -> new OffsetAndMetadata((entry.getValue()).offset(), "AQAAAXGhcf01")));
  kafkaConsumer.commitSync(updatedTopicPartitionToOffsetMetadataMap);`

  or specify metadata as `Af//////////` that means `NO_TIMESTAMP` in Kafka Streams.